# SharePoint 2013 (office 365) Multi value Managed metadata property in refiners

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, enterprise-search

I have a multi valued managed metadata property in office 365 called products and it only generated 2 crawled properties owstaxidProducts and Products. I tried to associate both to refinablestring01 and see some gibberish(seems like some guid and some value) in the refinement panel. Please help.

Comment: Why should not owstaxidProducts be enough as a refiner?

Comment: I'll try to replicate this in my tennant. I need to ask the basics though. Is your refiner Multi attribute set? (It should be by default.) When you added your refiner to the Refinement Web part, did you use the Multi-value Refinement Item display template?

Comment: I am also having this same problem adding refiners using Managed Meta-Data on Office 365 / Sharepoint Online. After associating with refineablestring01, it becomes available in the Refiners Web-Part but displays as "GPO|#8516df41-etcetc". So a GUID rather than the description. The refiners actually work perfectly to filter the search results but until i can get it to display the Title is worthless to me. The suggestion of trying the Multi attribute set template simply gives check boxes and allows multiple selection but does not help cleaning up the display of the Title. Any pointers releating

Answer (score 3):

When mapping a crawled property to a refinable managed property, you should select the crawled property with the ows_ prefix!

Don't forget to run the full crawl afterwards

Comment: Yep, that should be it. At least on premise this is usually the case :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd like to get a proper text displayed as a refinable string, you'd need to map ows_*NameofYourColumn* to a Refinablestring predefined value.

SharePoint crawl is creating two properties for managed metadata columns: ows_ and ows_taxid. The former is a pure text representation. While the later is a value of the managed metadata field with GUID and type associated.

If you'd have initially picked up the wrong mapping and changed it to the correct one later on, you'd need to wait a bit for Search crawler to pickup the correct mapping.

Here is a nice [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aatishblogs/archive/2014/02/02/refiners-for-managed-metadata-columns-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) covering this scenario. It is valid for SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint Online.

Answer (score -2):

You may get help from this link
[Search Refiners with Managed Metadata](http://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/search-refiners-with-managed-metadata/)

Comment: It looks like this post is for SharePoint 2010. The question is about SharePoint 2013 in Office 365. Refinement has changed considerably in the new version.

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link is broken, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)